# Add row when cell in table is not empty

Tags: vba, ms-word

This is the code that I have right now.

```
Do While IsEmpty(objTable.cell(intNoOfRow,2).Range.Text) = False
    intNoOfRows = intNoOfRows + 1
Loop
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

[`IsEmpty`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/Language/Reference/User-Interface-Help/isempty-function) tests to see if a `Variant` has a type of empty. It will always return `False` for a `String`. Test against `vbNullString` instead:

```
Do While objTable.cell(intNoOfRow,2).Range.Text = vbNullString
    intNoOfRows = intNoOfRows + 1
Loop
```

Comment: The codes do not work. It says Run time error '462. The remote server machine does not exist or is unavailable.

Answer (score 0):

We cannot use this code:
**IsEmpty(objTable.cell(intNoOfRow,2).Range.Text)** will always True, so the code will run into **Infinite Loop**. While **Len(.Cell(intNoOfRows, 2).Range.Text) <>0** always return True too. We are not sure if this is by design or bug, but the new cell always contains character.  **Cell(intNoOfRow, 2).Range.Text = vbNullString** doesn't work too.

Find a worked way on my side(**InStr( [start], string, substring, [compare] )** ):

```
With objTable
   Dim strCellText As String
   strCellText = .Cell(intNoOfRow, 2).Range.Text

Do While InStr(1, strCellText, "", vbBinaryCompare) <> 1  
           MsgBox "OK"
Loop
```

End With

Some old try:

```
With objTable
For Each c In .Range.Rows
intNoOfRows = intNoOfRows + 1
Next
End With
```

Or

You can use the **.Range.Rows.Count**, but the following code still need to adjust

```
With objTable
Do While intNoOfRows < .Range.Rows.Count
     intNoOfRows = intNoOfRows + 1
     'MsgBox .Range.Rows.Count
     'If intNoOfRows > .Range.Rows.Count Then
      '  Exit Do
     'End If

Loop
End With
```

Comment: The codes can't work.. There is something wrong with ".range". It says it is invalid.

Comment: You forgot With objTable/End With. Becasue the with block is reuse, so i don't copy it to every where

Answer (score 0):

Try something based on:

```
Sub Demo()
Dim r As Long, i As Long
With ActiveDocument.Tables(1)
  For r = 1 To .Rows.Count
    With .Rows(r)
      If Len(.Range.Text) = .Cells.Count * 2 + 2 Then i = i + 1
    End With
  Next
End With
MsgBox "There are " & i & " empty rows in the table"
End Sub
```

Similarly, to add a row before a non-empty row, you might use something like:

```
Sub Demo()
Dim r As Long, i As Long
With ActiveDocument.Tables(1)
  For r = 1 To .Rows.Count
    If Len(.Rows(r).Range.Text) > .Rows(r).Cells.Count * 2 + 2 Then
      .Rows.Add .Rows(r)
    End If
  Next
End With
End Sub
```